# Issue Tracker Items Download on click

Tags: tasks, download, issue-tracking

this feels like a very stupid issue, but I can't get around it. The default behaviour on my Issue Tracking List is to download the list item when clicked.

I want it to open in view or edit mode, but instead it tries to download a .000 file to my computer.

I have to click the ellipsis every time and navigate to "edit item" rather than just being able to click the line item.

Help?

Sylvie

Comment: is the task created by a custom workflow? i ask this becuase ".000" is a pointer to download files and this usually occurs in custom workflows when referencing the item url. in the url it produces it would give the ID of the item plus _.000 so somthing on the lines of /1_.000 which is not correct it should be ?id=1

Comment: I'm seeing this same behavior